# How to combine the data in 2 table, form the aggregation without duplicating the record by left join

Tags: mysql, sql

Now I am working with SQL files and have a question:
I would like to review the effect of the promotion campaign with the data in the sql file. In the SQL file there are 2 tables, web traffic and promotion campaign

The web traffic table, let's say table web are as follows

```
visitor_id purchase date traffic_source campaign_name country purchase_value
     1        1/1/2018       Search      promotion101    US      100
     2        2/1/2018       Direct      voucher02       UK      110
     3        2/1/2018       Search      buyme01         US       50
     4        3/1/2018       Banner      Example01       DE      130
     ..        .......       ...          ...            ..      ...
```

And in the second table I have the campaign information, let's say table promotion

```
Promotion_date campaign_name num_delivered promotion_fee 
  1/12/2017    promotion101      50           30
  2/12/2017    promotion101      30           20
  2/12/2017    voucher02         40           10
  3/12/2017    Example01         70           30
     ...             ...         ...          ...
```

In this case, I tried to use the left join to merge the table first but the record duplicated

```
Select 
   web.campaign_name, 
   sum(web.promotion_fee),
   sum(promotion.purchase_value)
FROM 
   web LEFT JOIN promotion 
   ON web.campaign_name = promotion.campaign_name 
GROUP BY 
   1
```

However, it doesn't work because the left join simply duplicate the record...
In this case, If I want to formulate the table like this:

```
Campaign_name Traffic_source Total_Customer Total_purchase_value Total expenditure 
 promotion101   Search         1000           2000                 1500
 Example01      Banner         2000           3750                 3000
```

Is it possible to do so? If yes then How can I make it?
Many thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: where the `total_customer`, `Total_purchase_value` `Total expenditure` values comes from?

Comment: Switch to  `GROUP BY web.campaign_name`. (group by ordinal position is not good programming practice.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may peform the aggregations of each table in separate subqueries:

```
SELECT
    w.campaign_name,
    w.purchase_value AS Total_purchase_value,
    COALESCE(p.promotion_fee, 0) AS Total_expenditure
FROM
(
    SELECT campaign_name, SUM(purchase_value) AS purchase_value
    FROM web
    GROUP BY campaign_name
) w
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT campaign_name, SUM(promotion_fee) AS promotion_fee
    FROM promotion
    GROUP BY campaign_name
) p
    ON w.campaign_name = p.campaign_name;
```

A critical assumption I have made here is that the `web` table contains data for all campaigns.  If not, then you might have to join to a third table containing all campaigns which happened.  Actually, arguably such a table should already exist.

Comment: It works and many thanks! And one extra things, in case there is some campaigns which does not included in the web table, then we have to join another third table. But for the sequence in joining table, does it matter like should I join the extra table first or it doesn't really important?

Comment: Here's the thing: Each table could have campaigns which are unique only to that table, so you don't really know which order to use.  If this be a real concern, then create a campaigns table.